# Access to error status of an Axios request not possible - status is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I use Axios to access my backend API. In my React frontend I want to catch different HTTP errors via the status to provide better feedback to the user.

When I get the status, I strangely get an undefined, even though the error object contains a status.

Do you know why? How can I access the stauts?

```
export const createBlog = async (token, workspaceId, userInputMetaData) => {
  log.info("Create blog.");
  const result = await axios.post(
    process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/workspaces/" + workspaceId + "/blogs",
    userInputMetaData,
    {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
    }
  );
  return result.data;
};
```

```
 const generateBlog = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await auth.getAccessTokenSilently({});
      const blog = await createBlog(token, workspaceStore.workspaces[0].id, userInputMetaData);
    } catch (e) {
      log.error(e.message)
      log.error(e.status)
      log.error(JSON.stringify(e))
    }
}
```

**Console output**

```
Request failed with status code 402

undefined

{  
"message": "Request failed with status code 402",  
"name": "AxiosError",  
"config": {    
  "transitional": {      
    "silentJSONParsing": true,     
     "forcedJSONParsing": true,      
     "clarifyTimeoutError": false    
  },    
  "transformRequest": [      null    ],    
  "transformResponse": [      null    ],    
  "timeout": 0,    
  "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",    
  "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",    
  "maxContentLength": -1,    
  "maxBodyLength": -1,    
  "env": {      "FormData": null    },    
  "headers": {      
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",      
    "Content-Type": 
    "application/json",      
    "Authorization": "Bearer ..."    
  },    
  "method": "post",    
  "url": "...",    
  "data": "..."  
},  
"code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",  
"status": 402
}
```

Comment: Try using `e?.response?.status`.

Comment: Ok, that works... but how? I didn't see the response object in my error object? How should I know that?

Comment: You are not printing the original object, you used JSON.stringify()

Comment: @laprof Because an error contains both `response` and `request` object. You could've known that if you'd've printed correctly. Do a `console.dir(e,{depth: Infinity})` and it'll print all of the it. Also, checking source code would've helped.